# Retrieve and access boolean from CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, boolean, fetch

I have made and entity with an attribute 'isLoggedIn' this gets set to true after a successful sign up / login. What I then need to do, is in my app start up loading screen, is retrieve whether this is true or false, and then use that result to activate 1 of 2 segues.

Here is what I have already to retrieve it (problem area):

```
var tasks : [Task] = []
func getData() {
    print("at least this worked")

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    do {
        tasks = try context.fetch(Task.fetchRequest())

        print("please let task work: \(tasks)")

    }
    catch {
        print("fetching failed")
    }
}
```

And this is what I have to save it:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let login = Task(context: context)
login.isLoggedIn = true

//Save that user is logged in below
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

And here is my entity / attribute setup:

[image]

Task.fetch request is predefined as

```
public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Task>
Declared In Task+CoreDataProperties.swift
```

The specific problem I have is that I don't know whether the bool I set is actually being saved or retrieved / and if so to both, then I cannot find a way to access the true / false / not set result.

What I am trying to do is to update the bool isLoggedIn to true when the user logs in successfully, and then, the next time the app is launched retrieve that true result and use it. How can this be done?

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Also, if the fetch is a problem somehow, it would be good to know what `Task.fetchRequest()` does.

Comment: I have edited the post to make it more informative

Comment: Please include what you are expecting to see, and what you are actually seeing. The code above is going to be making and saving a new Task entity every time it runs, and at no point are you reading the Bool property which is supposedly what your question is about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i will try to explain you what you need to do to first see the output of the result data

1st : - Retrieve your document directory path from your app document directory

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
    let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! String
    let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/filename")
```

2nd : You need a tool to see the database saved in that directory.
i recommend downloading this software to simplify your work

[SQLiteStudio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt?act=download)

Now just copy the path and paste in the explorer file, here you can see all the tables in your Db.sqlite file and check whether the values are being stored.

[image]

3rd : After you are sure that the value exists in the Db, Just fetch it and add IF statement to check the boolean value to select your preferred segue.